# XSLT - How to optimize a variable assignment based on multiple options

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following code:

```
  <xsl:variable name="attribute-name">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$var1 = 1">attr1</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$var2 = 1">attr2</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$var3 = 1">attr3</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>attr</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
```

that will be used for setting attributes in the later code:

```
  <tag>
    <xsl:attribute name="{$attribute-name}">Something</xsl:attribute>
  </tag>
```

I have to optimize the code because it really slows down my transformation process. I had a look at constructs like `select="if ()..."` but this only can be used in simple if-then-else situations. The code above can be extended by other `xsl:when`, so a maintainable solution would be nice.

Comment: (a) Performance depends entirely on which XSLT processor you are using, so you need to tell us this. (b) What is your evidence that leads you to conclude this construct is a performance bottleneck? (c) You've tagged it XSLT 1.0, but mention "if ()" which requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: (a) Saxon 6.5.5 (b) I added the feature above to existing code and I noticed a much longer runtime of the transformation process. Well, I did not measure/profile it. But if I'm right, the code above will be executed every time {$attribute-name} is used. So I thought optimizing it or using another realization would be increase the performance again. (c) You're right. The XSL file I modified is 1.0 and the solution should be conform to 1.0

Comment: The first thing I would try is to run it under Saxon 9.8. I've known that run 50 times faster, though I don't know exactly what features will cause that. Unless you're using Saxon XSLT extensions, it's very unlikely you'll hit any compatibility problems.

Comment: I'm using this code snippet for a DocBook modification. So therefore I have to switch over to the XSLT 2.0 stylesheets. I read between the lines that there is no "easy" transformation of my code, right? Another possibility (dirty hack) would be you using `sed` before the `saxon` run to replace the `{$attribute-name}` with the one I need. The attribute name will not change during the XSLT run.

Comment: Are you sure the DocBook 1.0 stylesheets don't work under Saxon 9.8? It would surprise me.

Comment: The style sheets are bundled with an extension that has never been ported to newer versions of saxon. http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/InstallingAProcessor.html#SaxonExtensions